# How to use webcam interface in JXBrowser 4.1

Tags: java, swing, chromium, jxbrowser

I am facing problem in JXBrowser 4.1 when i am trying to load a page with Webcam Interface. In Windows it showing me a blurred page while in mac it asking me to download Adobe Flash which i have already downloaded. Here i am attaching screenshot of windows. Please suggest me any solutions for this.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in the latest version that you can download from http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser